# How to sanitize html with next.js 13 server side?

Tags: reactjs, html-sanitizing, next.js13

How to sanitize html on next.js 13 server side?

`
import getData from '../../../firebase/firestore/getData';
import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';

export default async function Jbpregled() {
const data = await getData();

```
return (
    <div className="mt-4">
        <div className="px-4 sm:px-8 max-w-5xl m-auto">
            <h1 className="text-center font-semibold text-sm">Javne nabavke:</h1>
            <ul className="border border-gray-200 rounded overflow-hidden shadow-md">

                {data.map(item => <li key={item.id} className="px-4 py-2 bg-white hover:bg-sky-100 hover:text-sky-900 border-b last:border-none border-gray-200 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out">
                    {sanitizeHtml(item.tekst)}
                </li>)}
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

)
```

}`
Tryed this but still geting html tags...

Answer (score 0):

To Sanitize Html - Try [Isomorphic DOMPurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-dompurify).

This library makes it possible to seamlessly use **DOMPurify** (DOMPurify sanitizes HTML and prevents XSS attacks) on server and client in the same way.

**Sample Code for removing HTML**

```
const DOMPurify = require('isomorphic-dompurify');
const dirty_string = '<b>Hello There</b>';
let clean_string = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty_string, { USE_PROFILES: { html: false } });
console.log("Sanitized String = " + clean_string);
```

**How to configure DOMPurify ?** - https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/blob/main/README.md#can-i-configure-dompurify

Comment: Same, can you give me code example?

Comment: output is: <b>hello there</b>

Comment: With this i dont have use of html elements. Everything is plain text...